# How do I use data from a zip file?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2.4 and how do I use data from a zip file.I am trying to add a layer of a base map for south africa into my workspace by am not getting any joy.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the files from the zip file first?

Comment: Have you changed the setting 'Scan for contents of compressed files (.zip) in browser dock' from 'basic scan' to 'full scan'? Afterwards you can navigate into the zip files.

Comment: so I have found a way around it. cheers

Comment: i finally managed to extract the file, thanks Joseph, was somehow failing to extract the zip file firs.

Comment: zip as in some sort of compression file or zip as in some sort of postal address data?